# Remove /index.php/ from the URL with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

To note, I've found similar questions on StackOverflow but they have not worked as I need.

I have a URL such as:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/test
```

I'd like to remove the index.php directory, so if the above is entered it would go to:

```
http://www.example.com/test
```

This appears to work

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

However if the url is:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=example
```

It turns into

```
http://www.example.com/?option=example
```

So **index.php** should only be removed if it's a directory like in my first example.

Also if you type in for instance:

```
http://www.test.example.com/index.php/index.php/dfd
```

It should go to

```
http://www.test.example.com/dfd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rules below will:

- not apply for `/index.php?o=a`
- redirect `/index.php/index.php/dfd` to `/dfd`
- redirect `/index.php/index.php/dfd?a=b` to `/dfd?a=b`
- redirect `/index.php/index.php?a=b` to `/index.php?a=b`

.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+  
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/index\.php)+/?$ /index.php [R=302,L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php/?$
RewriteRule ((^|/)index\.php)+/?(.*)$ /$3 [R=302,L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Looks very close to working as needed. When I try this for example: http://example.com/index.php/index.php?option=random it doesn't remove the /index.php/ That url should go to http://example.com/index.php?option=random Otherwise your solution seems perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When using the updated code the site 500s.

Comment: To note I think the actual error it's putting in the log if it helps is: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Thanks, it no longer 500s, but the other item still happens. "When I try this for example: example.com/index.php/index.php?option=random it doesn't remove the /index.php/ That url should go to example.com/index.php?option=random "

Comment: Just to note, tried the latest updated version and while the issue from the last comment now works, the other items don't know such as going to example.com/index.php/eee goes to example.com/index.php/ rather than example.com/eee . Sorry to be a pain. If it's not dooable the original option you posted is pretty close and I can just hope that the other use case doesn't happen.

Comment: With the latest version when I go to example.com/index.php/ it doesn't appear to example.com it just refreshes the page. Also if I go to http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4:word-goes-here-page&catid=9&Itemid=101 it forwards to http://localhost/?option=com_content&view=article&id=4:about-your-home-page&catid=9&Itemid=101 Sorry I didn't realize this would be so tricky. I had hoped there would be a regex that can just replace any instance of "/index.php/" with "/" in a url. Appreciate all your effort.